# correct connection string syntax

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, database-connection

I have an ASP.NET application, which contains a simple database. I now want to upload my ASP.NET to the webhosting so that I can see it live.

I have published the app to my local computer, copied the files but I am getting the 500 Error `An error occurred while starting the application.`

I believe the error have been caused by the fact that I have used incorrect syntax when connecting to the database.

Here is what I have received from my website provider in order to correctly connect to the database:

```
<connectionStrings> <add name="TestSqlExpress" connectionString="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=W:\domains\DomainAddress\public\www_root\data\Database.mdf;Trusted_Connection=Yes;User Instance=True;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

Here is what I have been using so far, when connecting to my local MS SQL server in my ASP.NET app (under config.json)

```
"Data": {
"WorldContextConnection": "Server=ROBERT-PC\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=TheWorld;Trusted_Connection=true;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;"
}
```

Therefore once I uploaded my site via FTP to the hosting environment, I have changed my **config.json** to the following:

```
"Data": {
"WorldContextConnection": "data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDBFilename=W:\domains\DomainAddress\public\www_root\data\TheWorld.mdf;Trusted_Connection=true;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;Integrated Security=SSPI;User Instance=True;"
}
```

What did I do wrong under my connection string?

Comment: I would look up if your user is granted to the database correctly. Since it uses integrated security maybe the windows user is not setup correctly? Cannot see anything strange in your connectionstring.

Comment: Do you need to be using double backslashes in the data source and filename (e.g. .\\SQLEXPRESS, W:\\domains...)?

Comment: mar7r please make it as an answer. this solution worked like a charm

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that the config.json requires the backslash characters to be escaped, i.e.:

```
"Data": {
"WorldContextConnection": "data source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDBFilename=W:\\domains\\DomainAddress\\public\\www_root\\data\\TheWorld.mdf;Trusted_Connection=true;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;Integrated Security=SSPI;User Instance=True;"
}
```